# STM32 NUCLEO F401RE cannot write to some bits in GPIO BSRR

Tags: c, arm, embedded, stm32

I recently bought a [STM-NUCLEO](https://developer.mbed.org/platforms/ST-Nucleo-F401RE/) and I am trying to write to PA0,PA1,PA2,PA3 which are connected to LED's. The LED's connected to PA0 and PA1 light up as expected but PA2 and PA3 don't. I tried it with PA4 and that works too. Here is the code:

```
int main(void)
{

  /* Configure the System clock to 84 MHz */
  SystemClock_Config();

  RCC->AHB1RSTR |= RCC_AHB1RSTR_GPIOARST; // resetting GPIOA
    RCC->AHB1RSTR = 0; //exiting reset state
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOAEN; //enabeling GPIOA clock
    GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER0_0;
    GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER1_0;
    GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER2_0;
    GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER3_0;
    //setting the pins
    GPIOA->BSRR |= (1<<0);
    GPIOA->BSRR |= (1<<1);
    GPIOA->BSRR |= (1<<2);
    GPIOA->BSRR |= (1<<3);
  /* Add your application code here*/

  /* Infinite loop */
  while (1)
  { 

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Nucleo schematics](http://www.st.com/resource/en/schematic_pack/nucleo_64pins_sch.zip), PA2 & PA3 are connected to the internal ST-Link controller, therefore not usable for GPIO without adding and removing some bridges first.

That's your MCU, "SB62, SB63 Default open" means that the connection is not there.

[image]

And this is where it's connected to the ST-Link interface.

[image]